# Difference between submit(Runnable) and submit(Callable) in ExcectorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Bellow is the code for implementing Runnable class

```
public class ExecutorServiceWithRunnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        Future<emp> submit =null;
        emp emp = new emp();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
             submit = (Future<emp>) pool.submit(new RunnableClass(emp));
             try {
                    System.out.println(submit.get().getId());
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }


    }
}
class RunnableClass implements Runnable{

    emp e=null;
    public RunnableClass(emp emp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.e=emp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"...."+e.getId());
        e.setId(e.getId()+1);

    }

}
class emp{
    int id;
    String status;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

**Got out put is**:pool-1-thread-1....0Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NullPointerException at ExecutorServiceWithRunnableCallable.main(ExecutorServiceWithRunnable.java:15)

Below is the code for Callable

```
public class ExecutorServiceWithRunnableCallable2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        Future<emp> submit =null;
        emp emp = new emp();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
             submit = pool.submit(new CallableClass(emp));
             try {
                System.out.println(submit.get().getId());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
}
class CallableClass implements Callable<emp>{
    emp e=null;
    public CallableClass(emp emp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.e=emp;
    }

    @Override
    public emp call() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"...."+e.getId());
        e.setId(e.getId()+1);
        return e;
    }

}
```

**Got output is :**pool-1-thread-1....0
1
pool-1-thread-2....1
2
pool-1-thread-3....2
3
pool-1-thread-4....3
4
pool-1-thread-5....4
5

**So clarify me on future object returned by submit method in both scenarios.**

Comment: Runnable is like `void method(...)` and Callable is `Object method(...)`

Answer (score 4):

A `Runnable` does not return a result. So `Future::get` will still block until the runnable is done, but then just return `null`.

```
submit = (Future<emp>) pool.submit(new RunnableClass(emp));
```

This class-cast will produce a warning, because you are not actually getting a `Future<emp>` here. And because you ignored that, you got the exception later on.

Like the Javadoc says, you are really getting a `Future<?>`, which means (in this case) that you cannot use the result value.

```
submit = pool.submit(new CallableClass(emp));
```

If you want a result, submit a Callable. Note that no class cast was necessary, it can infer the generic type of the Future from the type of the Callable.